# POI SS UserModel Performance

Tags: apache, apache-poi, xssf, hssf

When using SS UserModel  to parse xls files, whats the difference in performance compared to HSSF?

Comment: while using hssf the performance will be good and but it uses more memory compared to ss usermodel.And while using hssf poi 3.7 user can export limited number of rows(65k).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For .xls files, there is no performance difference between the HSSF UserModel and SS UserModel. That's because the SS UserModel for HSSF is largely just some very clever retrofitted interfaces around the existing code.

The performance with .xlsx files (either direct calls to XSSF, or transparently through SS) is slower and more memory intensive than HSSF. The .xls file format is a binary one, .xlsx is an XML based one (a zip of XML files). Writing the code to process the XML is simpler, which is a good thing! However, the overhead of the xml parsing means that more memory is needed, and it's slightly slower.

Comment: Thank you very much. Iwasn't able to find a confiable answer until now